# When replacing #site-title with an image - why must it be located in root?

Tags: css, theme-twenty-eleven

I needed to replace the `#site-title` text with an image and I found a great blog post explaining this:

http://bentcorner.com/replacing-wordpress-twenty-eleven-site-title-with-an-image/

But it appears that the image to be placed in `background: url(/header.png) #fff no-repeat;` must always lie in the root directory (`~/public_html`).

I am using a Twenty Elven **child** theme and I tried to place the image file in the `images` subdirectory of the child theme, but when I do this no image is visible. So far, the solution described in the article only works if the image is placed in the root directory.

Why is that?

Is there a way to allow the image to be placed in the images subdirectory of the child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The / in header.png makes it look in the root directory.

Try just doing `background: url(header.png) #fff no-repeat;`

Comment: Thanks. I understand the role of the `/` but I tried `background: url(images/header.png) #fff no-repeat;` and various levels of `url(../../images/header.png) #fff no-repeat;` and that didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: What are the actual paths for the theme stylesheet and the image itself? I'm assuming /public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name has the stylesheet and /public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images has header.png?

Comment: OK I tried your suggestion as well and it didn't work. Actual path for the theme stylesheet: `/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child0/style.css`. Actual path for the image: `/public_html/wordpress/header.png`. Your help is much appreciated. +1 for now.

Comment: @ef2011 What if it's just `url(/wordpress/header.png)`? Actually, your goal is to have it in `/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child0/images` right?

Comment: OK, I just moved the image to the same directory as the `style.css` and your suggestion works: `/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child0/header.png`. The question now is whether placing it in the `images` subdirectory of the the child theme can work.

Comment: @ef2011 Well, for now, try `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child0/images/header.png`

Comment: Hmmm... placing the image in `/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child0/images/header.png` and updating style.css to have `images/header.png` now works! I could swear it didn't work before. Could the browser's cache be playing tricks on me?

Comment: haha, ya, that's possible. Glad it works now!